# Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'User' in type cast

Tags: flutter

I am trying to fetch and show posts but I am getting an error while pulling data from json.

**Model**

```
class Post {
  final String id;
  final User author;
  final String caption;


  Post({this.id,this.author, this.caption, }
  );


  factory Post.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap) {
    return Post(
      id: jsonMap['id'] as String,
      caption: jsonMap['caption'] as String,
      author: jsonMap['author'] as User,
   
    );
  }

  Map toMap(Post post) {
    var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();

    map["id"] = post.id;
    map["caption"] = post.caption;
    map["author"] = post.author;


    return map;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
  'id' : id,
  'author' :author,
  'caption' :caption,


  };
   String rawJson = jsonEncode(Map);

  @override
  String toString() {
    var map = this.toMap(Post());
    map["post"] = Post();
    return map.toString();
  }
}
```

I tried to use

```
final String author;
```

instead of the previous version

but when I try that it also gives me

```
Converting object to an encodable object failed: Map<dynamic, dynamic>
```

I need to declare it as User instead of String because I need to access the author's information (username,id etc..) in the post

Does anybody have a solution to this?

Update 1:
I am getting a "User" reference from Json Server so I have to refer it as User so I can refer to things like "User.email" etc..
I have the user declared like this

```
class User {
  final String id;
  final String email;
  final String username;

 User({
    this.id,this.email,this.username,
  });


  factory User.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
      id: json['id'] as String,
      email: json['email'] as String,
      username: json['username'] as String,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'id' : id,
    'email' : email,
    'username' : username,



  };

  Map toMap(User user) {
    var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    map["id"] = user.id;
    map["email"] = user.email;
    map["username"] = user.username ;


    return map;
  }


  @override
  String toString() {
    var map = this.toMap(User());
    map["user"] = User();
    return map.toString();
  }
}
```

Update 2:

```
Future<List<Post>> fetchPosts(http.Client client) async {
  final response = await http.get("$SERVER_IP/api/articles/?format=json");

  return compute(parsePosts, response.body);
}
List<Post> parsePosts(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  return parsed.map<Post>((json) => Post.fromJSON(json)).toList();
}
```

Update 3:
It is a UUID that i am getting both from author(it refers the author by id) and id .
Btw just so you know it is not firebase,it is Django so i can't use any firebase related code.

```
[
    {
        "id": "3ab6e7c8-6a4c-42c2-a08d-e8a6c0fcdecb",
        "author": "dbb0446d-d0ec-4c24-9c1e-8ca9b6b06a7d",
        "caption": "caption here",
       
    }
]
```

Comment: Please post your response JSON I will fix it

Comment: check the Update 2.

Comment: it's fine but I want to see JSON data which you are getting from API send response.body

Comment: Check update 3 please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that, because it is still a map!

The way of solving this, for example, in the `User` class would, be (I've made up the attributes!):

```dart
class User {
    String name;
    String lastName;

    const User({
        this.name,
        this.lastName,
    });

    factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return User(
            name: json['name'],
            lastName: json['lastName'],
        );
    }
}
```

Here were are using a `factory` constructor (again) but now we are parsing the json data (or the map) to a `User`. Then in the `Post` JSON constructor you have to use the `User` JSON constructor.

Comment: Check the update 1 . I already declared my User before,i don't see any difference compared to the code you wrote?

Comment: Well, there is. You don't have to cast the user. You have to do: `author: User.fromJson(jsonMap['author])` in the `Post` constructor. You are doing a `cast` which is not correct in this case. A cast is used to convert one type to another, not to create an object, and you have to create a `User` object.

Comment: now i get error `type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`

Comment: What does cause the error? Can you also add to the question a `print(response.body)`, please?

Comment: Then you can only save the UUID of the user. You should not be using a `User` object, but a `String`. Then, if you want the data of the user, you have to call it to the backend, or, if you are coding the backend, make it return the user data.

Comment: Read the question again please. I tried that solution before

Comment: Yes, still, the data is in the server. If you don't recieve the data from the server, you must get it. If not, you will not be able to reference the user information. 
Unless you already have your Users in a `Map` or any other kind of data structures in the app and you get the information from there.

Comment: I have realized that updating author `final String author;
`, Map<dynamic,dynamic> is caused from another variable. So i am seeing this case solved.

Comment: Perfect, I hope I have been helpful!

Comment: you did,thanks ! Map<dynamic,dynamic> problem was solved by removing `Map toMap()` and  `String toString()` functions in Post Model so i can see the post clearly now!